# Как стартовать сессию только для прошедших аутентификацию

Tags: php, cookie, сессия, аутентификация

Прошу помощи в связи с возникшей проблемой.

Задача: стартовать сессию только для прошедших аутентификацию с помощью конструкции `if (isset($_REQUEST[session_name()])) session_start();`

Проблема: после авторизации страница, на которую осуществляется переход, не получает значение `$_REQUEST[session_name()]`. Точнее говоря, его можно установить только принудительно передав:

```
$s=session_id();
echo '<a href="/?PHPSESSID=$s">На главную</a>;
```

Но даже после этого следующая страница, на которую осуществляется переход, опять не видит `$_REQUEST[session_name()]` с установленным значением.

Вопрос: что можно сделать, чтобы `$_REQUEST[session_name()]` получал значение без принудительного присвоения вышеописанным способом?

Установкой `session.use_cookies = 1` и `session.use_trans_sid = 1` (или 0) в php.ini ни на что повлиять не удалось, как и установкой `request_order = “GPС”` , описанной в статье http://diz-blog.com.ua/request-session-name-empty-what-do.html

Comment: Жесть...ну нельзя же вытворять такое....

     <a href="/?PHPSESSID=$s">

...элементарные правила безопасности как-никак, которые просто обязаны соблюдаться при разработке.

Comment: Да знаю я... Проблема в том, что не могу передать значение иначе, потому и спрашиваю совета, почему оно может не передаваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `if (isset($_REQUEST[session_name()])) session_start();` на `if ($_COOKIE[session_name()]) session_start();`.

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Добавлю от себя, вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится: чтобы проверка _$_COOKIE[session_name()]_ работала, [необходимо корректно удалять cookie](https://php.ru/forum/threads/ne-mogu-udalit-cookies.321/).

Answer (score 2):

Забудьте про передачу сессии в параметрах запроса!
Зная ссылку с сессией (а её сам пользователь может скинуть по неосторожности), любой человек сможет совершать действия от имени этого пользователя.

Лучше почитайте про сессии на оф. сайте https://php.net/manual/ru/intro.session.php

P.S. Есть замечательная суперглобальная переменная `$_SESSION`, которая позволяет работать с данными в сессии.

Comment: Я так и не смог добиться видимости значения REQUEST[session_name()] и запуска сессии с помощью конструкции

if (isset($_REQUEST[session_name()])) session_start();

Но видны cookie, установленные при авторизации и работает запуск сессии в такой конструкции
if (isset($_COOKIE)) session_start();

Является ли это полноценной рабочей заменой для запуска сессии только для прошедших аутентификацию пользователей?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по давности вопроса, автор уже разобрался.. Но кому-то может пригодиться.
@movak744 прав, `$_COOKIE[session_name()]` или, на крайний случай, `$_GET[session_name()]`

> P.S. Есть замечательная суперглобальная переменная **$_SESSION**, которая позволяет работать с данными в сессии.

Шикарный ответ, учитывая, что до старта механизма сессии этот массив будет пустым